# fullcalendarでdayclickした際に時間計測が出来るタイマーの様な画面に遷移させたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

お世話になります。

現在jqueryのプラグインであるfullcalendarを使用してcalendarを実装しています

そこで下記の様な問題に直面しています。

①dayclickをすると、他のJSファイルが呼び出される様にしたいが出来ない
※$.getscriptを使用し、jsファイルを指定しても404ステータスが表示される

```
$(#calendar).fullCalendar({

 dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view){
          $.getScript("welcome.js");
});
```

jsファイルの指定方法が間違っているのでしょうか？ちなみにcloud9で開発しています。

Comment: 実際のJSファイルにはアクセスできますか？またブラウザのWeb開発機能（F12）のネットワークタブを利用して404になっているJSのパスと本来置いてあるパスはどうなっていますか？

Comment: お忙しい中返答ありがとうございます！　ネットワークでパスを確認すると間違ってました‍♂️　非常に助かりました‍♂️

Comment: @渡久地太一 さん> 「パスを確認すると間違っていた」とのことですが、そのパスを修正することで質問内容が解決されたのでしょうか？もしその修正によって問題が解決された場合は、解決方法を[回答として投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60483/fullcalendarでdayclickした際に時間計測が出来るタイマーの様な画面に遷移させたい#post-form)し、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？